# Travelling to Texas from India - where will I pass through Immigration?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens

I'm travelling to San Antonio, Texas from Mumbai India, with connecting flights at London and Dallas/Fort Worth, USA (2.5 hours layover at each airport). All the tickets are booked through the same airline (American Airlines) and all the flights are on the same ticket. I am an Indian citizen, and travelling in US on a tourist visa (B-1/B-2). I am confused about the following things:

a) What will happen once I land in Dallas?
 Will I have to check out luggage and check back in again?
 Will I go through Immigration and Customs?
 And will all these be easy to manage with a 2.5 hour layover?

b) Will I go through Immigration/Customs again once I land in San Antonio?

c) Will I get boarding passes for all three flights at the same time (i.e. when I check in at Mumbai)?
If not, where will I need to collect them from at Heathrow and Dallas?

Comment: a, b, c: Yes, no, yes.  If for some reason you can't get all boarding passes at your initial check-in, you will be able to get them either at your departure gate or at a special desk for transfer passengers.

Comment: [This question is similar, and it has an answer with a great description of immigration](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77943/usa-customs-and-immigration/77946#77946) at your first port of entry, Dallas Fort Worth (DFW)

Answer (score 5):

a) Yes, you will have to clear Immigration, collect your checked baggage, then clear Customs, then recheck you luggage, then pass trough TSA to re-enter the terminal.  2.5 hours should be plenty.

b) No, you will clear US Immigration and Customs at DFW.  DFW-SAT is a domestic flight.

c) You *should* get all three Boarding Passes when you check in with BA in Mumbai. If not, the Agent will tell you what to do.  There is a BA transfer desk at LHR that can assist.

Comment: BA? The question says "American airlines". I have used AA several times for routes like London to San Diego via Chicago, and they always gave me both boarding passes.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan OP is originating in Mumbai.  The BOM-LHR sector would be flown by BA so the OP would check in with them.

Comment: Hi..Johns-305 is right... the first AA flight is operated by British Airways. Thanks for both your comments and replies - It'd be good to get all the boarding passes at once.